# How do I solve this one? It's irritating me!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve this question? I can't think of anything to do!

As $(x,y)$ ranges over all pairs of real values, what is the smallest value of:

$(2x-3y-4)^{ 2 }+(2x-3y+10)^{ 2 }$

Comment: $(x,y) = (-\infty,\infty)$ ?

Answer (score 6):

*Hint:* $(2x-3y-4)^{ 2 }+(2x-3y+10)^{ 2 }= 2(2x-3y+3)^2+98$.

Comment: Should it be equal to $2(2x-3y+3)^2 + 98$?

Comment: @PeidaTian Yes, of course, thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** This is a $1$-variable problem. Let $z=2x-3y$.

Answer (score 1):

prove that $(2x-3y+4)^2+(2x-3y+10)^2\geq 98$

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself "what number is half way between $-4$ and $10$"? $10-\frac{10-(-4)}{2}=10-7=3$

Using the previous calculation we have
$$\begin{array}{lll}
(2x-3y-4)^2 + (2x-3y+10)^2&=&((2x-3y+3)-7)^2 + ((2x-3y+3)+7)^2\\
&=&\dots
\end{array}$$